# python package is installed but not found in other directory

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I have created a conda environment and activated it already.

Then inside the `use_cases/` directory I execute: `pip install -e use_case_b` (https://github.com/geoHeil/dagster-demo/tree/master/use_cases):

```
...
...
Installing collected packages: use-case-b
  Attempting uninstall: use-case-b
    Found existing installation: use-case-b 0.0.0
    Uninstalling use-case-b-0.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled use-case-b-0.0.0
  Running setup.py develop for use-case-b
Successfully installed use-case-b
```

Now when inside the `use_cases/` directory:

```
python
import use_case_b
```

works fine.

When switching to a different directory like: `/` (= the root of the repository I get an error message of:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'use_case_b'
```

Why is it working once and failing in the second place? Could it be that it is not even working in the first place and only importing the sub_directory due to the `__init__.py` file?

How can I get the python package properly install into the virtual environment?

FYI: here you can find the full project https://github.com/geoHeil/dagster-demo

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import use_cases.use_case_b` in the second case?

Comment: Well yes and no - the thing is: yes, that works, but when in a different directory like `~/` this also fails. I guess this works due to the `__init__.py` files? How can I get this to install properly so the package is available from any directory like a regular python package?

Comment: I think your init.py file should contain what you want to import.

Comment: Well packaging own libraries takes more than just making  `__init__.py`. After all how can python know where your package is located on the disk? Search for Python Packaging guides. Can start from [there](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) for example

Comment: Try adding to the `__init__.py` file in the use_cases folder the following line: `from . import use_case_b`

Additionally you have to import the functions and classes you want to use from that folder in the `__init__.py` file inside that folder. E.g. `from .repository_b import use_case_b_repository`

Comment: But in https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/ it already says: /__init__.py is required to import the directory as a package, and can simply be an empty file. and

Comment: @Manumerous I am confused that you suggest this as subfolder `use_cases/ue_case_b` should be a self-contained repository. FYI: I have tried to follow the suggestions in https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/ now and created its own module folder. But so far, are still stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the cookiecutter to set up the package it works just fine.

https://github.com/audreyfeldroy/cookiecutter-pypackage

This is more like a workaround than an solution to the SF question - but works nicely and as an additional benefit has some best practices with regards to documentation and testing already built in.

Answer (score 0):

I normally face that problem when im using pip to install a package. Im not sure if this gonna work for you.

#### In the file you are importing the package copy the following code and run it.

```
from pip._internal import main
main(["install", "use_case_b"])
```

Just ignore the warnings'

**Good Luck,** Let me know if it works.